# Setting a Variable with and IF/OR Statement OR Calculation Results

Tags: excel, variant, vba

I'm stuck on a bit of code.  Essentially, I have a dynamic number of sheets where I'm trying to implement the same code.  I can get the code to look at the correct sheet, but I'm struggling with the variant.  The first line of code works, but only for 1 of the 2 values I'm looking for.

```
m = Application.Match(ws4.Range("D4").Value, .Columns("AW"), False)
```

To get the code to read D2 or D4, I've tried these lines of code, to no avail:

```
'm = Application.Match(ws4.Range("D4").Value, .Columns("AW"), False) Or Application.Match(ws4.Range("D2").Value, .Columns("AW"), False)
'm = ws.Range("AV").Value <> "0"
'm = ws.Range("AV").Value <> 0
'm = Application.Match(ws.Range("AV").Value) <> 0
'm = Application.Match(ws.Range("AV").Value <> 0)
'm = Offset(Application.Match(ws4.Range("D4").Value, .Columns("AW"), False), Application.Match(ws4.Range("D2").Value, .Columns("AW"), False))
```

When the actual code runs, this is what m is doing:

```
    txt_Name = .Range("E" & m).Value
```

Also, this is tied to a post on another forum.
https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1037378-convert-formula-vba-3.html

I think that if I can get this piece solved, I may be able to wrap up this project by end of day tomorrow, so I'm a little anxious.

Comment: `Match` returns double (a position relative to the range). If it doesn't find, it raises error. It'd be better if you explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You have a number of references to `.Columns("AW")` and in the last code line `.Range(...)`  - which worksheet are these meant to refer to - are you sure it is referencing the right sheet? It would be better to have an explicit reference here to a specific worksheet or worksheet variable.

Comment: ws4  is a sheet that holds some variables.  The overarching code that I'm trying to solve for is supposed to find the first instance on a Client sheet (the Client sheets are very dynamic, in that they get created when a Client is onboarded.)  The Client sheet is found when the User selects the Client's primary key from a combo box.  I have all of that figured out.  I have how to pull records into the form (that's the range "E" reference asked about above).  What I can't seem to do is, find the specific row, so that I can update the same record if need be.